# boost::unordered_map key class hash and equal methods

Tags: c++, boost, hash, dictionary, unordered-map

Is it possible not to declare another objects for hash generation and key comparasion,but to create member functions in key class for this capabilities?

Comment: `operator==` would work for the comparison, but what is the problem with providing a hash functor? It could just call a method of your key class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments you can easily define an `operator==` for your class. You can also write a free function `hash_value` that takes a parameter of your class, and this should be used automatically.

Comment: Must the hash be a global function, or it could be in a namespace (class namespace, for example)?

Comment: @user14416 to be used automatically it must not be part of a namespace. If you're willing to specify the hash function explicitly in the `unordered_map` definition then you can use anything you want.